# How to embed a WebGL output in May Keynote?

Tags: webgl, powerpoint, beamer, keynote

I have some output in WebGL format, is there a way for me to embed this in a KeyNote or PowerPoint or LaTeX-Beamer presentation so that I change the orientation and zoom during a presentation.

Answer (score 1):

Might be useful.
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/25946/how-to-add-live-web-pages-to-a-powerpoint-presentation/

I am not sure if you can configure which rendering engine to use, if it's using IE's rendering engine, which doesn't support webGL, erm...

Either way, try searching further more for some iframe, live-web-page insertion, but in a way that it supports webGl context.

Comment: I will try this, but is there anything that will work on a Mac? This add-in does not seem to work with a Mac.

Comment: I do not use Mac so I cannot test it, but:
http://smallbusiness.chron.com/embedding-live-stream-keynote-45310.html
http://keynoteuser.com/2009/02/08/k09-tip-where-did-web-view-go/
Might be useful. But is it such a big problem to minimize presentation and show page in pre-opened web browser? Cheers.